# How to get company listing in QB desktop and some other questions

Tags: quickbooks

I have to create an integration app for Quickbooks Desktop (first) and Quickbooks online (later). App is to only read and save data in local mssql DB, which is gonna be accessed from a web site. Data of interest are : list of companies, list of each company accounts and ledger info.

Since this is a web app - integration app (asp.net/c#) I plan to create a web service to be called by QB's Web Connector app.

I installed / run WCWebService from SDK samples, authenticate web method returns path to QB db file or empty string to use currently opened db file.
Is there a way to get list of company files out of quickbooks, 
Also then my app has to enumerate company list, open each file and read required set of data from it, is it possible at all ?

Do I understand correct: there is no single web api to access both QB desktop and online ?
(I read a couple of artiles on it and people said that: QB Desktop -> QBSDK/Web Connector, QB Online -> IPP REST api. However I see that quickbooks desktop allows to upload it's local DB file to be accessed from web.)

Thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get list of company files out of quickbooks

No.

> Also then my app has to enumerate company list, open each file and read required set of data from it, is it possible at all ?

You can certainly read data from them, yes. You won't be able to get a list of company files though without some end-user interaction (the end-user needs to go through a connection process *for each file*).

> there is no single web api to access both QB desktop and online ?

Correct.

> (I read a couple of artiles on it and people said that: QB Desktop -> QBSDK/Web Connector, QB Online -> IPP REST api.

This is correct.

- SDK/Web Connector for QuickBooks DESKTOP
- REST v3 API for QuickBooks ONLINE